# Check if a UITableViewCell is selected, and the cell went off screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-cell, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a custom UITableViewCell that `dequeueReusableCells`. I have an int called `selectedRow` which gets the selected rows number in the method of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. I then pass `selectedRow` to an int called `rowNumber` which is in the class of my customCell.

In `customCell.m`, I have the method `prepareForReuse`. In that I made an NSLog of `rowNumber`.

What I want to do is: if a row is selected and that row went off screen, then perform some code. I would probably have to use `prepareForReuse`, but I don't know what to do in it.

I know it's a bit complicated, but if you have any questions, then I'd be happy to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to call `prepareForReuse` directly as it would be called automatically:

> this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the
>   UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:.

and as you *don't know what to do in it*, note:

> For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell
>   that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and
>   selection state

[UITableViewCell Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `- (void)tableView:tableView didEndDisplayingCell:cell forRowAtIndexPath:indexPath;` in `UITableViewDelegate` to know which cell is scrolled off screen.

However, this method is iOS6+ only.

Comment: I have to do it in the customCell.m, which doesn't have the class of `didEndDisplayingCell`

Comment: @MikeRally you can call your code in `customCell.m` from the  `cell`.

Answer (score 0):

You're over complicating things. You don't have to do prepareForReuse the in the custom cell.

Take a look at this. 
http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

Its pretty similar for storyboards.

Comment: I think you have a wrong link, cuz it doesn't have a tutorial, its only a title

Comment: Did you go through it? It has sample code near the bottom.